# Django RelatedManager nesting to access nested fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    order_name = models.CharField(max_length=10,unique = True, default = "")

class LineItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name="items")
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, related_name="prod")
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default = 0) 

class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    product_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
```

So I am trying to create an APIView PUT Request to be able to change Order contents. So my create method in OrderItemSerializer is not working correctly. I'm new to Django.. def update(self, instance, validated_data):

So basically I am unable to complete this function.

This is the structure of my instance -

```
{
    "order_name": "OrderA",
    "line_items": [
        {
            "product": {
                "id": 7,
                "product_name": "ProdA",
                "product_price": "23.99"
            },
            "quantity": 2,
            "product_total": 47.98
        },
        {
            "product": {
                "id": 9,
                "product_name": "ProdC",
                "product_price": "19.99"
            },
            "quantity": 23,
            "product_total": 459.77
        }
    ],
    "cart_total": 507.75
}
```

Serializers.py

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['product_name','product_price']

class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    line_items = LineItemSerializer(many=True, source='items')

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['order_name', 'line_items', 'cart_total']

    def create(self, request):
        serialized = self.serializer_class(data=request.DATA)
        if serialized.is_valid():
            serialized.save()
            return Response(status=HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class LineItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = LineItem
        depth =1
        fields = ('product', 'quantity', 'product_total')
```

Views.py

```
class LineItemList(APIView):

    def get(self,request):
        lineitemlist = LineItem.objects.all()
        serializer = LineItemSerializer(lineitemlist,many = True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request):
        snippet = LineItem.objects.all()
        serializer = LineItemSerializer(snippet, data=request.data, partial = True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, order_name):
        snippet = self.get_object(order_name)
        snippet.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

class OrderList(APIView):

    def get_object(self, order_name):
        try:
            return Order.objects.get(order_name=order_name)
        except Order.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self,request):
        orderlist = Order.objects.all()
        serializer = OrderSerializer(orderlist,many = True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = OrderSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def put(self, request):
        body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
        body = json.loads(body_unicode)
        order_name = body['order_name']
        snippet = Order.objects.get(order_name=order_name)
        serializer = OrderSerializer(snippet, data=request.data, partial = True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request):
        body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
        body = json.loads(body_unicode)
        order_name = body['order_name']
        snippet = self.get_object(order_name)
        snippet.delete()

class OrderDetail(APIView):

    def get_object(self, order_name):
        try:
            return Order.objects.get(order_name=order_name)
        except Order.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, order_name):
        snippet = Order.objects.get(order_name=order_name)
        serializer = OrderSerializer(snippet)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

The problem is that if I use RelatedManager(reference line_items from the instance I am unable to go any level further). I only get the option to choose between product, quantity and ids..
Update method I am struggling with

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    listitems = instance.items.get(product_name = validated_data.get("product_name"))
    items = instance.items.return_set(validated_data.get("product_name"))

    items = instance.objects.items.all().select_related('product').select_related('product_name')
    items = items.product_name
    instance.save()
    a = items.get('product_name'= validated_data.get("product_name")

    asper= key.get(product_name=validated_data.get("product_name"))

    items.product.get(produc_name=validated_data.get("product_name")
    for prod in items.product.all():
        if prod.product_name==validated_data.get("product_name"):
            prod.quantity = validated_data.get("quantity")
            prod.save()
    return instance
```

Comment: can you add your serializer and views?

Comment: @JPG added views and serializers.

Comment: What you mean by ***I am unable to go any level further*** ?

Comment: apart from that, you don't need to access and decode the **`request,body`**, because the ***parsed version of input data*** will be available in **`request.data`**

Comment: I wan't to access product_name in the JSON above. Starting point is the "instance" in the update method. I am able to go upto products level but any further field access is apparently prohibited. Because of some "reverse relationship" thing. I'm not able to do something like instance.items.products.product_name. Can only go to instance.items depth. Pretty clueless now

Comment: Where is your update() method?

Comment: I've tried multiple times to get it to work but it wouldn't. My Update method is in OrderSerializer file. and is defined like def update(self, instance, validated_data):

Comment: add the code snippet, you are only mentioning the  ***function name*** in code. You have to add the *function definition*

Comment: ``` def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        listitems = instance.items.get(product_name = validated_data.get("product_name"))
        items = instance.items.return_set(validated_data.get("product_name"))

        items = instance.objects.items.all().select_related('product').select_related('product_name')
        items = items.product_name
        return instance``` .  Like I just said. I didn't get anywhere with the function. I just need a way such that I can loop and compare product_names with my validated_data

Comment: add it to the question,

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. It's added now

Comment: @JPG any suggestions in this case? Still stuck